# Is it possible to move an ec2 instance to diffreent vpcs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm a new user of aws. After I've created a ec2 instance, I found this instance belongs to different vpc what my team assumes.

So I want to move this instance's to other vpcs. Is it possible?

**what I want is..**

my-instance (vpc A)
-> my-instance (vpc B)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot move the instance. But you can make an image (an [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)) of your instance and launch an instance in the new VPC. It will be the same as the original. [This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-to-create-a-new-ami-from-a-snapshot-and-launch-a-new-vm/) on TechRepublic is a nice walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks for your great comment. I already have an AMI of this instance. So I follow the walkthrough of the article.